# Why does this snippet's statements' order of execution alter according to a promise's rejection/resolution?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

Consider the following snippet:

```js
function func1() {
  return Promise.resolve();
}

function func2() {
  func1()
    .then(res => console.log("In func2 'then'"))
    .catch(err => console.log("In func2 'catch"));
}

function func3() {
  Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      func2();
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("In func3 'then'");
    });
}

func3();
```

Its execution generates the following output:

```
In func2 'then'
In func3 'then'
```

If `func1`'s returned value is substituted for `Promise.reject()`, like this:

```js
function func1() {
  return Promise.reject();
}

function func2() {
  func1()
    .then(res => console.log("In func2 'then'"))
    .catch(err => console.log("In func2 'catch"));
}

function func3() {
  Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      func2();
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("In func3 'then'");
    });
}

func3();
```

, the promises' callbacks get executed in a different order, yielding:

```
In func3 'then'
In func2 'catch
```

That is the observed output order in both node and chrome.

What is going on here? Why does `func2`'s 'catch' has a different execution priority from its 'then'?

The snippet is rather weird, but I wanted to know why such behaviour occurs - is it the collateral effect of some implementation detail, or the illustration of a general scheduling policy?

Answer (score 1):

The promise chain initialized in `func3` isn't actually connected to the promise chain initialized in `func2`; with your

```
.then(() => {
  func2();
})
```

since the result of `func2` isn't being returned, the promise from `func2` isn't connected to the chain in `func3`. What you're seeing comes down to millisecond timing: if one Promise resolves (or rejects), and another Promise *not chained with it* resolves (or rejects) at basically the same time, which chain's `.then` or `.catch` runs first? It's not intuitive, and isn't the sort of logic your code should depend on.

If you switch around the `.then` and the `.catch` in `func2` while using `Promise.resolve`, you'll see the same sort of behavior as in the second code - the `func3` log runs before the `func2` log.

```js
function func1() {
  return Promise.resolve();
}

function func2() {
  func1()
    .catch(err => console.log("In func2 'catch"))
    .then(res => console.log("In func2 'then'"))
}

function func3() {
  Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      func2();
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("In func3 'then'");
    });
}

func3();
```

Best solution: never depend on microsecond timing, instead always chain your Promises by `return`ing them (no matter whether you're in a standalone function like `func2`, or inside a `.then`), so everything is chained together, and things will be completely predictable:

```js
function func1() {
  return Promise.reject();
}

function func2() {
  // return the chain:
  return func1()
    .then(res => console.log("In func2 'then'"))
    .catch(err => console.log("In func2 'catch"));
}

function func3() {
  // return the chain (just in case consumers of func3 want to use the chain):
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      // return the chain:
      return func2();
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("In func3 'then'");
    });
}

func3();
```

Now, it's clear that `func2`'s chain will always completely finish before moving on to the `In func3 'then'` (no matter whether there's an error or not), because the `func2` chain is being returned inside `func3`'s `.then`.

Comment: I realize this snippet seems a bit weird. Actually, I came across this behaviour while writing some tests for the callback of a browser event, analogous to `func2`. I was more interested in why it occurs. I'll edit my answer to clarify my intent.